# Disjoint Union of Subsets and Direct Sum of Subspaces (Proof)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ B $ be a basis of the vector space $V$.
Suppose 
$$ B = B_1 \cup \cdots \cup B_n $$
for some subsets $B_{i}$ of $B$. 
Let $W_i = \mathrm{Span} (B_i) $.

Show that the following are equivalent:

- the $B_i$'s are pairwise disjoint, and
- $ V = W_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus W_n $.

While I understand the intuition behind why the disjoint union of subsets and direct sum of subspaces are analogous, how should one prove this? How can I show that the intersection between the $ W_i $'s are $ \{ \boldsymbol{0} \} $?

Comment: You surely mean that the $B_{i}$ are pairwise disjoint.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, of course, edited to clarify.

Comment: Would you mind if I edit your post for further clarity? You can always rollback my edit if you don't like it.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Sure. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the key point will be that given the assumption on the $B_{i}$, then for each $i$ we have
$$
W_{i} \cap (W_{1} + \dots + W_{i-1} + W_{i+1} + \dots W_{n}) = \{ 0 \}.
$$
(It is not enough to show that the $W_{i}$ intersect pairwise in zero.)

And this is easy: if
$$
w_{i} = w_{1} + \dots + w_{i-1} + w_{i+1} + \dots w_{n}
$$
for some $w_{i} \in W_{i}$, then
$$
w_{1} + \dots + w_{i-1} - w_{i} + w_{i+1} + \dots w_{n} = 0,
$$
and now use the fact that $w_{i}$ is a linear combination of the elements of $B_{i}$, and that the $B_{i}$ are disjoint, and their union is a linearly independent set.